# Datos que muestra un DataGridView en C#

Tags: c#, sql

¿Cómo saber si un `DataGridView` muestra la misma información cada vez que ejecuta una consulta de SQL?

---

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        data.DataSource = "";
        /* Cargar datos */
        data.DataSource = CCarsData.ConexionDB.CargarTable();
        /* Set Grid */
        setdv();

        comparar();
    }

    private void comparar()
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in data.Rows)
        {
            string Valor = Convert.ToString(Row.Cells[0].Value);
            string status = Convert.ToString(Row.Cells[2].Value);

            foreach(DataGridViewRow row2 in data2.Rows)
            {
                string Valor2 = Convert.ToString(row2.Cells[0].Value);
                string status2 = Convert.ToString(row2.Cells[2].Value);

                if (Valor == Valor2)
                {
                    if (status == "DISPONIBLE" && status2 == "SERVICIO")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("El vehiculo " + Row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + " se encuentra disponible", "Flota", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    }
                }
            }               
        }
        data2.DataSource = "";
        /* Cargar datos */
        data2.DataSource = CCarsData.ConexionDB.CargarTableServicio();
        setdv2();
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
```

---

El `grid1` se carga con la tabla artículos, y el `grid2` se carga con los artículos que tienen estatus servicio.

Mi aplicación es meramente informativa no realiza operaciones CRUD a la base de datos.

*****EDIT****

Realicé unos cambios al código ya que en principio estaba redundando.

1. En el `grid1`cargo todos los artículos
2. En el `grid2` cargo solo los artículos con estatus "SERVICIO"

Es decir:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        /* Cargar datos */
        data.DataSource = CCarsData.ConexionDB.CargarTable();
        data2.DataSource = CCarsData.ConexionDB.CargarTableServicio();
    }
```

3. Al iniciar el `timer` solo refresco el `grid1` y comparo con el ´grid2´

   private void comparar()
       {
           timer1.Enabled = false;

   ```
       foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in data.Rows)
       {
           string Valor = Convert.ToString(Row.Cells[0].Value);
           string status = Convert.ToString(Row.Cells[2].Value);

           foreach(DataGridViewRow row2 in data2.Rows)
           {
               string Valor2 = Convert.ToString(row2.Cells[0].Value);
               string status2 = Convert.ToString(row2.Cells[2].Value);

               if (Valor == Valor2)
               {
                   if (status == "DISPONIBLE" && status2 == "SERVICIO")
                   {
                       MessageBox.Show("El vehiculo " + Row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + " se encuentra disponible", "Flota", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                   }
               }
           }               
       }
       data2.DataSource = "";
       /* Cargar datos */
       data2.DataSource = CCarsData.ConexionDB.CargarTableServicio();
       setdv2();
       timer1.Enabled = true;
   }
   ```

Con esto solo hago una comparación entre todos los artículos y solo los que están con estatus servicio

Comment: puedes agregar un label con la fecha/hora en que se ejecutó la consulta seguido de la cantidad de filas :D

Comment: no funcionará porque siempre traerá los mismos artículos, la aplicación es para ser manejada en tiempo real, es decir, cada vez que un vehículo cambie de estatus, el grid reflejará el cambio

Comment: En ese caso ve por SignalR que permite crear apps en tiempo Real para tecnologías .net :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿No sería más fácil manejar un campo en tu tabla de fecha de modificación/Estado para no comparar toda la tabla?

Si de igual manera deseas comparar las tablas (veo que solo comparaste dos columnas), te dejo un ejemplo con Linq.

```
    private void Comparar()
    {
        var dataSource1  =CCarsData.ConexionDB.CargarTable();
        var dataSource2 = data.DataSource;

        var iguales =
            dataSource2.AsEnumerable()
                .Join(dataSource1.AsEnumerable(), table1 => table1.Field<string>(0),
                    table2 => table2.Field<string>(0),
                    (table1, table2) => new { table1, table2 })
                .Where(
                    @t =>
                        @t.table1.Field<string>(0).Equals(@t.table2.Field<string>(0)) &&
                        @t.table1.Field<string>(2).Equals(@t.table2.Field<string>(2)))
                .Select(@t => @t.table1);
        var distintos = from table1 in dataSource2.AsEnumerable()
                        where !iguales.Contains(table1)
                        select table1;
        if (distintos.Any())
        {
            foreach(var distinto in distintos)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("El vehiculo " + distinto[0] + " se encuentra disponible", "Flota", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

            }
        }
    data.DataSource=dataSource1;
    }
```

Tal vez con esto tu rendimiento mejore.

Saludos